# Bitmap to integer array?

Tags: android, bitmap

in my application i have a database where i store image .i want to retrieve images.images are easly retrieve in BitMap but the problem is how can i convert that BitMap image into integer format.

this is code:

```
   DataBaseClass objOfDataBaseClass=new DataBaseClass(context);
    Cursor mCursor=objOfDataBaseClass.showData();//here is all data taken from dataBase

if(mCursor.moveToNext()) {

        byte[] mg=null;
        mg = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mg, 0, mg.length);

         int[] store=?//how can i bitMap store in this array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Bitmap.getPixels` method ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)))

```
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
int[] store = new int[width * height];
bitmap.getPixels(store, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store the pixels of the bitmap itself, as a bitmap contains the image in uncompressed form and that would result in a huge amount of data (e.g. 1024 x 768 x 32 bit is 3.1 MB).

Better compress the bitmap to e.g. an PNG and store that in the database. You can use [Bitmap.compress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) for that purpose and use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write the data to. Then, store the bytes of that outputstream to your database.